Attempting to create a Proxy
I have to create a Proxy, first I created my own then I found out that is better to use TransparentUpgradeableProxy.sol
My initial logic implementation.
The upgraded implementation.
This is the proxy contract .
When I attempt to set the value in the initial implementation using
Set value on Impl 1
cast send 0x6956Cd3c767ffFCFe1077164aE204789DCE09C6B setValue(uint256) 4288876 --rpc-url https://ethereum-sepolia-rpc.publicnode.com --private-key xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Error: 
server returned an error response: error code -32000: execution reverted

While attempting to debug it using
cast call 0x6956Cd3c767ffFCFe1077164aE204789DCE09C6B implementation()(address) --rpc-url https://ethereum-sepolia-rpc.publicnode.com
Error: 
server returned an error response: error code -32000: execution reverted

And finally I tried
cast call 0x6956Cd3c767ffFCFe1077164aE204789DCE09C6B implementation()(address) --rpc-url https://ethereum-sepolia-rpc.publicnode.com
Error: 
server returned an error response: error code -32000: execution reverted

It appears that something is wrong with the Proxy contract, but it is verified on Etherscan.
Any idea?

First of all, your contract ZeppelinProxy deployed at 0x6956Cd3c767ffFCFe1077164aE204789DCE09C6B is not the TransparentUpgradeableProxy contract, instead it's the deployer of your TransparentUpgradeableProxy contract.
Your deployed TransparentUpgradeableProxy contract is 0x60Da46a609f92DA1aDE987e49abbEf25cBfB2C8E.
So, the correct command should be:
cast send 0x60Da46a609f92DA1aDE987e49abbEf25cBfB2C8E "setValue(uint256)" 4288876 --rpc-url https://ethereum-sepolia-rpc.publicnode.com --private-key xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

I've set the value as 5000 by executing this command:
cast send 0x60Da46a609f92DA1aDE987e49abbEf25cBfB2C8E "setValue(uint256)" 5000 --rpc-url https://ethereum-sepolia-rpc.publicnode.com --private-key xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

NOTE: The value remains unchanged in the implementation contract because it doesn't use its own storage. All storage operations are performed on the proxy. This is by design and ensures the implementation contract can be replaced without losing or modifying state stored in the proxy.
You can check the same by fetching the value from the TransparentUpgradeableProxy contract:
cast call 0x60Da46a609f92DA1aDE987e49abbEf25cBfB2C8E "value()" --rpc-url https://ethereum-sepolia-rpc.publicnode.com

The output would be:
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001388

which is the bytes representation of 5000.
You can convert the same to decimal using cast --to-dec command, like:
cast --to-dec 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001388


P.S., There is no implementation() function in the TransparentUpgradeableProxy, but there is a _implementation() function which is having internal visibility, so you can't access that using the cast call command.
Also, I've created this test contract which can potentially help you to understand the flow and functionality better, particularly for the upgrading part and the retrieval of the deployed proxy admin contract at the time of deployment of the TransparentUpgradeableProxy from the emitted event, because OpenZeppelin v5 TransparentUpgradeableProxy creates / deploys its own ProxyAdmin contract. You can refer to this answer for more details.

I don't see where the proxy is upgraded with the updated implementation.

It’s not upgraded, because you haven’t called the upgradeAndCall function. You can refer to this test function to see how you can call that on the ProxyAdmin contract.
